What is the word for a statement or testimony made by an author about his/her own work-- its nature, aim, and scope?
In the world of art, I believe it's usually just called "Artist's Statement." What about a serious writer, philosopher, or literary critic who gives a short description or declaration about the nature, aims, and intention of his/her own work? Is there a concise and commonly-used expression?
I appreciate the responses so far but recognize now that I didn't make my question sufficiently clear. It was not at all about a single book, but a person's oeuvre, indeed, his entire life's work, both as philosopher and professor of literature. The specific context: I've written a book about a prominent scholar and have included two statements--each one about a page in length--found in his university employment file. In the index of the book, I need to have a subheading for these documents. "Mission statements" sounds too corporate. "Writer's statements" doesn't work either.

There are lots of Google hits for Writer's Statement.

By "work" do you mean a single book and not their oeuvre?

I appreciate the responses but recognize now that I didn't make my question sufficiently clear.  It was not at all about a single book, but a person's oeuvre, indeed, his entire life's work, both as philosopher and professor of literature. The specific context: I've written a book about a prominent scholar and have included two statements--each one about a page in length--found in his university employment file. In the index of the book, I need to have a subheading for these documents. "Mission statements" sounds too corporate.  "Writer's statements" doesn't work either.

What do those talk about? Who wrote them?

Can you give any examples? I'm not aware of having run across such things, at least formalized, not counting stray comments made in interviews about one's life's work, etc.

A manifesto, maybe?

One problem with the question is that the "writer" (the prominent scholar) may be confused with the "author" of the book. The "short description or declaration about the nature, aims, and intention of the work" is a synopsis, but the reader may think that it applies to your book, rather than the  "person's oeuvre". And it doesn't indicate that the text was written by that person.

@Graffito Presumably this would be put into a block quotation, so it will be clear it's the writer's statements, not the author's. Surely a book about a writer will have lots of such quotes.

If these are some documents that you found in his university employment file, then they have presumably been submitted by him to satisfy some demands of the university's bureaucracy. If so, then the bureaucracy must have given them some name when asking for them. Apart from satisfying such bureaucratic requirements, and creating blurbs for their books, writers normally don't declare the 'nature, aims, and intention' of their work in separate documents; they are supposed to be clear from the work itself.

For her work in general:

Mission statement
Manifesto

For a particular piece of work:

Introduction
Preface
Background
Prologue


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Summation is the sum total of something. By definition, it is for math but it can be used in other instances. "Artist's Works Summation" then would be the artist's summing of their works.
